# What is the meaning of perf script output?

Tags: performancecounter, perf

I used the perf script command to view the result of the perf.data file, but I don't really understand what each column means. For example, if I have the following result:

```
perf  3198 [000] 13156.201238: bus-cycles:  ffffffff81086e90 resched_task

perf  3198 [000] 13156.201267: instructions:  ffffffff811868e9 do_vfs_ioctl
```

What are the values `3198`, `[000]`, `13156.201238` referring to?

Comment: what exact command did you run to get this output?

Comment: perf record -a, followed by perf script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is output from the default list of `--fields` ( `-F` is equivalent ), it looks like `pid`, `cpu` and `time` from the list of the available fields. You can verify that using the

```
perf script -F pid,cpu,time
```

if it will have the same first fields in output.

If not, there is probably no better way than to try the other fields from manual page (there is no good documentation).

Comment: Bit more information about fields: "Comma separated list of fields to print. Options are: comm, tid, pid, time, cpu, event, trace, ip, sym, dso, addr, symoff, srcline, period. Field list can be prepended with the type, trace, sw or hw, to indicate to which event type the field list applies. e.g., -f sw:comm,tid,time,ip,sym and -f trace:time,cpu,trace"
Check this: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-perf-script/